# Ruby on Rails, Bootstrap& Buttons

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Rails and Bootstrap and I'm trying to create large 100x100 pixel buttons with a large image at the top and text below.

I'm using the follwing code in the view (partial):

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-vehicles btn-header-maint">
        <%= image_tag ("glyphs/Vehicles.gif" , :size => "66x66") %>
        <br></br>
        <%= link_to( "Vehicles", :controller => 'vehicles') %>
        </button>
```

The problem is that only the text is working as a link, not the whole button. I've messed around for hours trying to solve this. Can anyone help with the correct structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest links within `<button>` tags.

You probably want to just use the link itself as the button, put the content inside it, and style it appropriately:

```
<%= link_to( "Vehicles", :controller => 'vehicles') do %>
  <%= image_tag ("glyphs/Vehicles.gif" , :size => "66x66") %>
  <br></br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks meager that's perfect. final code: '<%= link_to( "Vehicles", :controller => 'vehicles', :class =>"btn btn-large btn-vehicles" ) do %>
   <%= image_tag ("glyphs/Vehicles.gif" , :size => "48x48") %>
   <br></br>
   Vehicles
   <% end %>

Comment: @jared, if this worked for you consider accepting the above answer :)

Comment: Thanks meager - first post from a newb